# ngCordova oauth and security

Tags: cordova, oauth, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I've been experimenting with the [ngCordova oauth](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) plugin which uses the inappbrowser plugin to open up a new browser window so the user can login and then return to the app with oauth access tokens.

This new browser window doesn't show a URL bar by default, so it wouldn't be possible for a normal user to tell that they are entering their details into the real google oauth address (let a long a https URL).

I've tried creating my own plugin, and setting the location=yes, but then the user is presented with a really crap looking browser which doesn't instill any confidence either.

My question is, how do others get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use the visually awful browser
2. Use the system browser "_system"

Even if you show the user the URL it can still be spoofed.  I wouldn't be too concerned about showing vs hiding it.  Just don't ask for an excessive amount of permissions for a particular provider.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'll give the system browser a go, thanks Nic, but as for "Just don't ask for an excessive amount of permissions for a particular provider." - what if the user is requested to login, then the malicious website could collect their login credentials. This is common if using the default browser, because the user wouldn't have an existing session in it.

Comment: Hey Nic, I've tried the '_system' method, which works a lot better (as the user is indeed already logged in most of the time), but the addEventListener doesn't seem to get triggered when the callback URL is called so instead of close()'ing it, it has a server not found message. Any idea's?